Bookmark last comma-separated value before specific separator using Notepad++ regex
I have a list of text data formatted as follows:
Drtyjtyjnt
11,825,222
Ftyryer
8,823,623
Strtrtuperd
8,542,448
Ts
7,153,156
Supd
7,122,304
Su.3
6,920,743
Supld
dddd
tgtgtg
Sd
April 1991
/////////////////////////
Freeeer
7,537,583
Dufdgnt
4,381,322
SioBup
3,010,937
S
2,238,608
Du
SuperM
Sup
August 1989
/////////////////////////
D
12,184,781
S
9,023,965
Fog
8,913,781
Supe
7,441,191
May 1991
/////////////////////////

I want to bookmark the last comma-separated value before each ///////////////////////// separator using Notepad++ regex. For example, in the list provided, the following lines should be bookmarked:
6,920,743
2,238,608
7,441,191

I have attempted to use the following regex patterns but they did not work:
(?-s)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?=(?:(?!\R/////////////////////////).)*\R/////////////////////////)
(?s)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?=(?:\R(?!/////////////////////////).)*\R/////////////////////////)

Could someone help identify what might be wrong with these regex patterns or provide a working solution?

Try ^\d+(?:,\d+)*$(?=(?:\R(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*)*\R/{3,}$), see the regex demo.

@WiktorStribiżew it working good - send as answer that I can accept it

You can use
^\d+(?:,\d+)*$(?=(?:\R(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*)*\R/{3,}$)

See the regex demo
Details

^ - start of a line
\d+(?:,\d+)* - two or more comma-separated digit sequences
$ - end of a line
(?=(?:\R(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*)*\R/{3,}$) - a positive lookahead that requires (immediately to the right of the current location):

(?:\R(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*)* - zero or more occurrences of

\R(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$) - a line break not followed by a line that only contains comma-separated digit sequences
.* - the rest of the line


\R - a line break
/{3,}  - three or more / chars
$ - end of a line



NPP test:

